# Merge with multiple records at once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

There is a piece of code, from a previous dev, that is doing a merge statement with variables, and processing one record at time.

I'm sure the merge can deal with multiple records at one.

```
create table dbo.Staging
(
    transactionID bigint not null primary key nonclustered,
    transactionDate date not null,
    productId int not null,
    orderId int not null,
    qty int not null,
    unitPrice decimal(8,2) not null
)

create table dbo.Transactions
(
    transactionID bigint not null primary key clustered,
    transactionDate date not null,
    productID int not null,
    ReferenceOrderID  int not null,
    Qty int not null,
    ActualCost decimal(8,2) not null
)
insert into dbo.Staging(transactionID,transactionDate,productId,orderId,qty,unitPrice)
values(1001,'20210101',45889,1501,5,105),
      (1002,'20210102',45892,1503,2,8),
      (1003,'20210103',45555,1555,5,5),
      (1004,'20210104',44444,1444,4,4)

insert into dbo.Transactions(transactionID,transactionDate,productId,ReferenceOrderID,qty,ActualCost)
values
      (1003,'20210101',41111,1111,1,1),
      (1004,'20210101',41111,1111,1,1)
```

The code is much longer, but the here is the code :

```
declare 
    @bi_transactionID bigint ,
    @bi_transactionID_init bigint =0,
    @d_transactionDate date,
    @i_productId int,
    @i_orderId int,
    @i_qty int ,
    @dm_unitPrice decimal(8,2)


SELECT @bi_transactionID = MIN(s.transactionID)
FROM dbo.Staging as s
WHERE s.transactionID > @bi_transactionID_init

WHILE @bi_transactionID is not null
BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @bi_transactionID= s.transactionID,
            @d_transactionDate=s.transactionDate ,
            @i_productId =s.productId,
            @i_orderId =s.orderId,
            @i_qty = s.qty,
            @dm_unitPrice = s.unitPrice
        FROM dbo.Staging as s
        WHERE
            s.transactionID = @bi_transactionID

        MERGE dbo.Transactions AS T
        USING (SELECT s.transactionID FROM dbo.Staging as s WHERE s.transactionID = @bi_transactionID) AS s
        ON (t.transactionID = s.transactionID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE  SET 
                transactionDate = @d_transactionDate,
                productId = @i_productId,
                ReferenceOrderID=@i_orderId,
                qty = @i_qty,
                ActualCost = @dm_unitPrice        
    
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (transactionID,transactionDate,productId,ReferenceOrderID,qty,ActualCost)     
        VALUES (@bi_transactionID, @d_transactionDate,@i_productId,@i_orderId,@i_qty,@dm_unitPrice);

        SET @bi_transactionID_init = @bi_transactionID

        
        SELECT @bi_transactionID = MIN(s.transactionID)
        FROM dbo.Staging as s
        WHERE s.transactionID > @bi_transactionID_init
        
END
```

I believe it can be done in one statement, with merge with out the while and varibles.
Can this be done ?

Answer (score 3):

Is this the right ? from my side, the results are the same...

```
MERGE dbo.Transactions AS T
        USING (SELECT s.transactionID,s.transactionDate,s.productID,s.orderID,s.qty,s.unitPrice FROM dbo.Staging as s) AS s
        ON (t.transactionID = s.transactionID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE  SET 
                transactionDate = s.transactionDate,
                productId = s.productId,
                ReferenceOrderID=s.orderId,
                qty = s.qty,
                ActualCost = s.unitPrice        
    
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (transactionID,transactionDate,productId,ReferenceOrderID,qty,ActualCost)     
        VALUES (s.transactionID, s.transactionDate,s.productId,s.orderId,s.qty,s.unitPrice);
```

Comment: It is right. Why transactionID is nonclustered in table. dbo.Staging ? It should be Clustered Index .

Comment: It's a non clustered index , because Staging table it's heap table, for fast insert. It's not having a clustered index, thanks

Comment: I doubt, if it is benefiting you in any way.Transactionid as Clustered Index will help in you in both Insert/Select

Comment: @KumarHarsh, In the Staging table, somehow, we don't "care" about it. There are less then 20k records, because we are truncating at the start of the load process, thanks

Comment: @KumarHarsh Actually that's incorrect in this case. To maximize performance of an `INSERT` into a **Staging Table** (especially for large datasets), you shouldn't have any indexes on the table at all, especially not a **clustered index** since a Heap will have the fastest initial load. Having no indexes also allows [parallel inserts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/real-world-parallel-insert-what-else-you-need-to-know) to occur. For subsequent querying against that **Staging Table**, after loading, then the appropriate indexes can be added (usually just **nonclustered**).

Comment: @J.D., Initially I meant,instead of NCI, CI will be better in every scenario, moreover Transactionid is ever increasing, so Insert in Staging and merge both will be benefited.Yes I agree if there is no index at all then performance of an INSERT will improve.It is a trade OFF.It really depend upon situation.In most of the situation Having one ever increasing CI on INT column help.

Comment: @J.D. [That's](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-empty-clustered) [not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) [true](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/real-world-parallel-insert-select-what-else-you-need-to-know/ba-p/305329). `TABLOCK` should sort it out in most instances. An IDENTITY column is one of the few exceptions and there you can use `ROW_NUMBER` combined with `IDENTITY_INSERT`

Comment: @Charlieface I don't follow how anything you said is relevant to what I said. Yes, using the `TABLOCK` hint *can* improve performance of *large* data `INSERTS`, nothing I said debates that, I agree. `IDENTINITY` is not the same thing as **indexing**, and is also irrelevant to what KumarHarsh and I were discussing. In fact the 3rd link you posted in your comments supports what I said: "*Have Additional Indexes? Watch out!
...it is important to note that the presence of a clustered index or any additional non-clustered indexes on the target table will disable the parallel INSERT behavior.*"